# Find sum of an attribute for each object in an array

Tags: swift, swift3

What is the best way to find the sum of an attribute for an array of objects. Lets say I have an array of type item. item has attribute price. How can i sum each item.price inside an array of items. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the `reduce` function on the array of items:

```
struct Item {
    var price: Double
}

let items = [Item(price: 2), Item(price: 3), Item(price: 7)]

let total = items.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.price })

print(total) // 12
```

You can also use a more traditional loop as well.

```
var total = 0
for item in items {
    total += item.price
}
```